# How to change the numbering of section and subsection

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I would like to see my sections as for example `3-1` instead of `3.1`

How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Use `\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{section}-\arabic{subsection}}`, best in the preamble in this case

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! For instance, `\renewcommand\thesection{\thechapter-arabic{section} }`, if you class of document  has chapter above section.

Comment: What is your `\documentclass`?

Comment: tnx. my documant class is thesis

Comment: @masoud: There are 1,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000  different `thesis.cls` out there ;-) Which one do you mean?

Comment: I use this template

Comment: http://mathdept.iut.ac.ir/sites/mathdept.iut.ac.ir/files/Master_thesis.rar

Comment: @masoud: Your `thesis.cls` uses `report.cls` at the backend. On a quick check I could not detect a redefinition of `\chapter` or `\section` or `\thesection`

Comment: On the second glance that template class is a little bit clumsy.

Comment: @Christian Hupfer: Why not Avogadro's number differents thesis.cls?

Comment: @Bernard: Don't be silly -- don't exaggerate ;-) The Avogadra number is for the number of `thesis.cls` in the whole universe only. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

If an `article` - like documentclass is used, then redefinition of `\thesubsection` is basically sufficient, if this kind of numbering is requested.

Each LaTeX counter has a predefined `\the...` command which defaults to use `\arabic{...}`, i.e. printing the counter value with arabic numbers.

The structure commands use a somewhat recursive setup, referring to the upper level:

`\thesubsection` is usually defined as `\thesection.\arabic{subsection}`, i.e. if `\thesection` is redefined, `\thesubsection` will use the different format as well.

This works for `book` or `article`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{c@chapter}{% No, chapter counter is not available
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{section}--\arabic{subsection}}
}{%
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection--\arabic{subsection}}
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit -- Update**

```
\documentclass{report}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter,\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection--\arabic{subsection}}


\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}

\end{document}
```

Comment: probably `--` rather than `-`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Agreed, it does look better, but I would use this numbering style myself at all. Thanks for proposition

Comment: thank you this works for subsections but not for sections the results are like 5,3-3 !

Comment: @masoud: What does `5` mean here? The chapter number?

Comment: yes 5 is the number of chapter

Comment: @masoud: And there's a comma `,` after the chapter number?

Comment: yes comma is shown always after the chapter number. even in picture captions

Comment: @masoud: See the update please

Comment: stil like before chapter and section seperated by commma!

Comment: oh its worked thank you very much. change this line {\thechapter,\arabic{section}} to {\thechapter--\arabic{section}}

Comment: @masoud: Your question is quite unclear: I thought you wanted to have the the comma

Comment: my problem is solved thanx for your time and passion

Comment: Just one more ! Is there another \renewcommand for picture and table captions to show them like 5-3?

Comment: @masoud: You're are constantly changing the question -- this is not really ok! By the way, it's just `\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thesection--\arabic{figure}}` and similar for tables