# Change part numbers to words in arabic

Tags: parts, naming

In a similar manner shown in

[Change chapter numbers to words in Arabic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176858/change-chapter-numbers-to-words-in-arabic)

How can I write "Part one" instead of "part 1" but in Arabic:

Replace the word "part" with
"الجزء" since the word
"القسم"
Is not appropriate.

I was able to do this replacement using the command:

```
\gappto\captionsarabic{\renewcommand{\partname}{الجزء}}
```

HOwever, I do not know how to replace the number with its arabic translation written in letters

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,margin=2.5cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm]{geometry} 

\usepackage{hyperref} 

\usepackage{arabluatex}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{6} 
\setcounter{tocdepth}{6}
    

\usepackage[bidi=basic,layout=lists.tabular]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar,mapdigits,main]{arabic}
\babelprovide[import=en,language=Default]{english}

\babelfont{rm}{Latin Modern Roman}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{Simplified Arabic}
\babelfont[english]{rm}{Times New Roman}








 %%%%%  END MACRO Litteral Numbering of chapters 
     
    \newcommand\words[1]{\expandafter\xwords\csname c@#1\endcsname}
    \def\xwords#1{\ifcase#1\or
    الأول\or
    الثاني\or
    الثالث\or
    الرابع\or
    الخامس\or
    السادس\or
    السابع\or
    الثامن\or
    التاسع\or
    العاشر\or
الحادي عشر\or 
الثاني عشر\or 
الثالث عشر\or 
الرابع عشر\or 
الخامس عشر\or 
السادس عشر\or  
السابع عشر\or
الثامن عشر\or 
التاسع عشر\or 
العشرون\or 
    \else
    I need more words أحتاج إلى المزيد من ترقيمات الأبواب بالحروف في ملف arbbook.cls\fi}

     
    %next three lines is to make chapter naming use the above wordings (literal numbering in Arabic words)

% The below commands so that chapter name apear in header as Chapter one instead of chapter1
\usepackage{etoolbox} 
\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\Hy@org@chapter}
  {\begingroup \renewcommand{\thechapter}{{\words{chapter}}}}
  {}
  {}
\patchcmd{\Hy@org@chapter} 
% Controls how chapter namin apear in table of contents
  {\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}}
  {\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\@chapapp\space\words{chapter}\space#1}}
  {}
  {}
\apptocmd{\Hy@org@chapter}
  {\endgroup}
  {}
  {}
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}
  {\thechapter}
  {\words{chapter}}
  {}
  {}
\makeatother
 
 


% The below commands so that part name apear in header as part one instead of part 1
\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\Hy@org@part}
  {\begingroup \renewcommand{\thepart}{{\words{part}}}}
  {}
  {}
\patchcmd{\Hy@org@part} 
% Controls how part namin apear in table of contents
  {\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\protect\numberline{\thepart}#1}}
  {\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\partname\space\words{part}\space#1}}
  {}
  {}
\apptocmd{\Hy@org@part}
  {\endgroup}
  {}
  {}
\patchcmd{\@makeparthead}
  {\thepart}
  {\words{part}}
  {}
  {}
\makeatother


% part Naming
\gappto\captionsarabic{\renewcommand{\partname}{الجزء}} %to name the part title   الجزء instead of القسم

% Chapter Naming
\gappto\captionsarabic{\renewcommand{\chaptername}{الباب}}
 
\gappto\captionsarabic{\renewcommand{\appendixname}{الملحق}}






\begin{document}

\part{تمهيد}
\chapter{شكر وتقدير} 
\subsection{سيشسي}
\subsubsection{شسيسشسي}


\end{document}
```

Comment: You might try with   the `fmtcount` package, which uses .ldf files. As far as I know there's no .ldf file for  arabic, but you could make one yourself.

Comment: @Bernard, the attached link, he managed to do something similar using a different approach

Comment: in what way does the linked answer no answer the question?

Comment: The \part macro differs from \chapter macro, we might use an analogous approach, able to change the  word "part" to "الجزء" by using

\gappto\captionsarabic{\renewcommand{\partname}{الجزء}}

However, I could not achieve literal numbering of parts and do not know how to set their appearance in the TOC

Comment: you just need to replace "chapter` by "part" so  `\renewcommand\thepart{\words{part}}` with `\words` as defined there

Comment: Tried it but did not work, nothing happened

Comment: I have added a MWE

Answer (score 1):

Here is the general mechanism provided by `babel` to set locale dependent counters and redefine strings. There are some simplifications, but note the ‘words’ counter appears in the section number (you may redefine it, however). Requires a relatively recent version.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,
            margin=2.5cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm]
           {geometry} 

\usepackage{hyperref} 

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{6} 
\setcounter{tocdepth}{6}

\usepackage[english, bidi=basic, layout=lists.tabular]{babel}
\babelprovide[
  import,
  mapdigits,
  main, % Space separated list. Use braces in multi-word items:
  counters/words = الأول الثاني الثالث الرابع الخامس السادس السابع
     الثامن التاسع العاشر {الحادي عشر} {الثاني عشر}]{arabic}

\babelfont{rm}{Simplified Arabic} % The main font for the main lang
\babelfont[english]{rm}{Latin Modern Roman} % Secondary font/lang

\renewcommand{\thepart}{\localecounter{words}{part}}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\localecounter{words}{chapter}}

\setlocalecaption{arabic}{part}{الجزء}
\setlocalecaption{arabic}{chapter}{الباب}
\setlocalecaption{arabic}{appendix}{الملحق}

\begin{document}

\part{تمهيد}
\chapter{شكر وتقدير} 
\subsection{سيشسي}
\subsubsection{شسيسشسي}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The words counter appearing in section number is odd, is there a way to set it?

Comment: The commands 
\setlocalecaption{arabic}{part}{الجزء}
\setlocalecaption{arabic}{chapter}{الباب}
\setlocalecaption{arabic}{appendix}{الملحق}
Are useful, however, the numbering code won't be good enough for use, also will it cause issues in the table of contents?

Comment: `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}`. See, for example, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278299/how-to-change-the-numbering-of-section-and-subsection . The best way to redefine the TOC format is with a package: options are `titletoc`, `tocloft` and `etoc` – see https://ctan.org/topic/toc-etc .